# Contradiction proofs

Tags: proof-writing

I'm a first year Physics student and I have some trouble approaching Proofs by Contradiction in some of my Math classes. Once I get the first 2 or 3 statements I can finish the proof but a lot of the time I can't immediately get the first step. Any tips to approach this better (some examples would be helpful)?

Comment: Could you please provide an example?

Comment: For example - The proof that there are infinite number of primes (Euclid)

Comment: @DoYouEvenScienceBro: This proof is not (necessarily) a proof by contradiction.

Comment: Yes but I'm trying to gain an intuition of how to use that method specifically so I'd like to use that in this case

Comment: There are plenty of examples on this side (for example listed on the right hand sided under "Related") which might give you some tips.  Such as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451328/a-proof-by-contradiction

Comment: In addition, I'll say many so-called  ‘proofs by contradiction’  are not really so. Infinity of primes (in Euclid's proof) is a typical example: indeed it is proved that any finite list of primes is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

There are infinite number of primes.

The proof by contradiction is as such:

Suppose to the contrary there exists a finite number of primes.

Let's call this set of finite number of primes

$$p_1\text{,...,}p_n$$

If you add 1 to this set, we have a new set and we shall denote this new set as S:

$$S=\left\{p_1\text{,..., }p_n\text{$\}$+1}\right.$$

There are thus 2 cases:

This new set could be prime or it could not be prime.

Case 1: This set is prime

If this set is prime, then we are done for we have shown that there exists another prime number outside the original finite set.

Case 2: This set is not prime

If this set is not prime, then

$$\left.\text{S-$\{$}p_1\text{,..., }p_n\right\}$$ can be divided by some prime.

The difference after subtraction is 1.

But recall that the only integer that can divide 1 is 1 but 1 is not a prime number.
So we conclude that only initial assumption of there being finitely many primes as false.

Comment: What does $\left\{p_1\text{,..., }p_n\text{$\}$+1}\right.$ mean? I know you mean that you add $1$ to the product of primes $p_1 p_2 \cdots p_n$, but I've never seen addition being performed between a set and a real number

Comment: Also, see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30127/is-there-an-intuitionist-i-e-constructive-proof-of-the-infinitude-of-primes