# Prove property of symmetric difference: if $A \triangle B \subseteq A$ then $B \subseteq A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

This problem is from Velleman p143 5.

**Recall from Section 1.4 that the symmetric difference of two sets A and B is the set $ A \triangle B = (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A) = ( A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B) $. Prove that if $ A \triangle B \subseteq A $ then $ B \subseteq A $.**

---

My strategy: The crux of this proof is to reduce $ ( A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B) $ down to the fundamental logical form. $ (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A) = (x \in A \land x \notin B) \lor (x \in B \land x \notin A) $. This gives us a disjunction where if either case is true, then $  x \in A $.

---

My proof:

Let x be an arbitrary member of B. Suppose that $ A \triangle B \subseteq A $. All the members of $ A \triangle B $ are in either A or B, but not both. The case where $ x \in A \land x \notin B $ is not applicable since $ x \in B $. That leaves the case where $ (x \in B \land x \notin A) $. Since $ x \in B $, we know that $ x \in A \triangle B $ and we're given this means that $ x \in A $. Therefore $ x \in B \to x \in A $. Since x was arbitrary, we assert that $ B \subseteq A $.

---

My issue: The proof seems OK, I think. The Velleman Proof Designer seems to jive with my argument. However, it's really bothering me that the logical decomposition involves $ (x \in B \land x \notin A ) \to x \in A $. How can x be a member of A and at the same time not be a member of A?

Comment: If $A \triangle B \subset A$, then you must have $B \setminus A = \emptyset$. Hence $B \subset A$.

Comment: That helps. A = {1, 2, 3, 4}. B = {4}. $ B \setminus A =  \emptyset $. $ A \triangle B = \{1, 2, 3 \}\subseteq A$ is true. $B \subseteq A$ is also true. This all works. I guess I just need to accept $(x \in B \land x \notin A) \to x \in A$ as a strange consequence of the logic.

Comment: Think of it this way, $A \triangle B$ is made of two parts, (i) parts of $A$ that are not in $B$ and (ii) parts of $B$ that are not in $A$. If $A \triangle B \subset A$, then the (ii) parts must be empty or you have an immediate contradiction, and so $B \setminus A$ is empty.

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344393/prove-that-if-a-mathop-triangle-b-subseteq-a-then-b-subseteq-a

Answer (score 1):

You are right that it is not possible for "$x$ [to be] be a member of $A$ and at the same time not be a member of $A$". That is in fact the point.

Assume $x\in B$. Then by the statement $(x \in B \land x \notin A ) \to x \in A$, if `$x$ is not in $A$` then it is in $A$. That is a contradiction, so our hypothesis `"$x$ is not in $A$"` must be false. Therefore, $x\in A$.

That last paragraph shows $x\in B \implies x\in A$. Therefore, $B\subseteq A$. That is the very last statement of the argument.