# Prove that if $A\Delta B\subseteq A$ then $B\subseteq A$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

Not a duplicate of

[Prove that if $A \bigtriangleup B\subseteq A$ then $B \subseteq A.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2399533/prove-that-if-a-bigtriangleup-b-subseteq-a-then-b-subseteq-a)

[Prove that if $A \mathop \triangle B \subseteq A$ then $B\subseteq A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344393/prove-that-if-a-mathop-triangle-b-subseteq-a-then-b-subseteq-a)

This is exercise $3.5.5$ from the book *How to Prove it* by Velleman $($$2^{nd}$ edition$)$:

Prove that if $A\Delta B\subseteq A$ then $B\subseteq A$.

Here is my proof:

Suppose $A\Delta B\subseteq A$. Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $B$. Suppose $x\notin A$. From $x\in B$ and $x\notin A$, $x\in B\setminus A$. Ergo $x\in(B\setminus A)\cup(A\setminus B)$. From $A\Delta B\subseteq A$ and $x\in(B\setminus A)\cup(A\setminus B)$, $x\in A$ which contradicts the assumption that $x\notin A$. Therefore $x\in A$. Thus if $x\in B$ then $x\in A$. Since $x$ is arbitrary, $\forall x(x\in B\rightarrow x\in A)$ and so $B\subseteq A$. Therefore if $A\Delta B\subseteq A$ then $B\subseteq A$. $Q.E.D.$

Is my proof valid$?$ Is there a way to prove the above statement directly $($not using proof by contradiction$)?$ If there is, then please provide me with hints and not complete answers.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: I do not see any faulty of your proof; it seems correct.

Comment: A direct proof?  I'd say. $A\triangle B = (A\cap B^c)\cup (A^c\cap B) \subset A$ but $A^c\cap B\subset A^c$ is disjoint from $A$ so $A^c\cap B=\emptyset$ so for all $x \in B$ then $x \not \in A^c$ which means $x \in A$ and $B\subset A$.  That's not a proof by contradiction per se... but it does use the excluded middle.  Which I think is unavoidable if you are make statements *directly* about negative occurance (which the concept of $A\triangle B$ intrinsically is.)

Comment: Before your opening "Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $B$", you may add "If $B=\emptyset$, there is nothing to prove." As for a proof without the use of contradiction, you could use $A \Delta B=(A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B)$ perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If $B\Delta A= (B\setminus A) \cup (A\setminus B) \subset A$, what can you say about $B\setminus A$?

Comment: It says that $B\setminus A=\emptyset$ and ergo $B\subseteq A$.

Comment: Yes, exactly ... !

Answer (score 1):

Your argument looks good. For a direct proof:

$$A\triangle B = (B\backslash A) \cup (A\backslash B)$$

Thus, $$B\backslash A \subset A.$$ On the other hand

$$ B\backslash A = B \cap A^c \subset A^c.$$

So
$$ B\backslash A \subset A \cap A^c = \emptyset.$$

Therefore $$ B \backslash A = \emptyset$$
and $B\subset A$ follows.

Answer (score 1):

An identity is $$B = ((B \Delta A) \cap B) \cup (A \cap B)$$

(an $x \in B$ is either not in $A$ and then it's in the left hand side, *or* it is in $A$ and then it's in the right hand side)

Now we apply that $A \Delta B \subseteq A$ so that

$$B \subseteq (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap B) = A \cap B \subseteq A$$

and we're done.